# $(this).animate({ top: 200 }, 500); TOP to be a variable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

It is hard for me to explain so I will just demonstrate what I am trying to do:

This work fine:

```
$(this).animate({ top: 200 }, 500);
```

I'm trying to replace the 'top' value by a variable

like this:

```
var x = 'top';    
if (condition) { x = 'left'; }    
$(this).animate({ x: 200 }, 500);
```

But this fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
var pos = {'top':200};    
if (condition) { pos = {'left':200}; }    
$(this).animate(pos, 500);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing an object - define it beforehand like this.  Where x can be anything, i.e. 'top', 'left', etc.

```
obj[x] = 200;

$(this).animate(obj, 500);
```

Comment: No.. it can be anything.  Although animate will only accept CSS properties.

Comment: I understand what he wants, which is to build a dynamic animation. The properties object can still have the keys the same CSS only props.

Comment: It will NOT break the animate function if he passes in a complex object that has properties besides CSS properties.  I'm speaking in generic terms here because its important.

Answer (score 0):

Top is a [parameter](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). You can pass any CSS properties.

> A map of CSS properties that the animation will move toward.

Comment: He is asking how to pass in variable/dynamic CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but you could use this to compute object keys if you use ES6:

```
x = 'top';    
if (condition) { x = 'left'; }    
$(this).animate({ [x]: 200 }, 500);
```

Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)